# Check of my first Eagle boards

Tags: pcb-design, can, termination

I am attaching two boards I have just designed in Eagle and would appreciate if any expert around here willing to take a quick look would flag any obvious errors in the design.

[image: CanSwitch board]

[image: CanRelay board]

There is one board that would serve as a light switch PCB, sending a CAN message over the CAN bus. There would be plenty of them (I plan about 40-ish).

The other board is the final relay board. There would be just two, one for each floor. And SSR boards I already bought would be connected to the relay boards (which in turn would switch the lights in the house on and off).

I will also connect my USB interface to the CAN network (to the USBTIN 3 pin header in the relay) to be able to debug it (and in the final version also control from an ODROID over a web application). For pure debug purpose of the Microchip pins I have the DEBUG 5pin header in each board too.

Any hints or questions WRT to the design would be much appreciated. I plan to use a Cat 5 cable with RJ45 plugs. The switch boards therefore have double RJ45 plugs on them, and they all would be powered up on the bus line directly (only the relays have the power jacks). I know that is out of spec for CAN, but I plan to run al low baudrates, and right now I have 50 kbit/s in the code (see the link above), but more than happy to go way down.

Perhaps a question is WRT to the terminating resistor. I have been reading mixed recommendations on this one. Obviously the datasheet suggest using two 60 ohm resistors connected via a SPLIT pin. That assumes a 120 ohm cable, which I do not plan on using, I plan to use plain Cat 5 (which is said to be 100 ohm if I got this right). Then others propose using a resistor to match the cable impedance, which would mean two 50 ohm resistors instead.

I went for a bit of compromise so far (also because the local shop does not actually have 60 ohm resistors) and plan to put 56 ohm resistors there now. I do have oscilloscope too and plan to play around with that too if needed.

I indeed plan to play with this way more once built on my table before putting it out in our to be built house :) So far I only played with this setup on a breadboard.

For those interested in more background of what I am doing, check my GitHub account here (all the boards are there as well): https://github.com/PoJD/can-pcb and https://github.com/PoJD/can

Comment: I haven't taken an extensive look, but I'd use some stitching vias between the two planes on the boards.

Comment: Thanks! You mean to connect the ground pours on both sides more? I thought the pads of all the components would do, or is better to place a few more vias there to kinda help the ground planes? Surely can do that, thanks :)

Comment: What kind of caps are you using.. they all seem rather small?

Comment: You mean the capacitors? :)I bought them locally here, they are small ceramic capacitors. Should fit in there, did not create any components for those, just used some built-in in Eagle

Comment: Ya you ought to be using axial capacitors with holes the right distance apart for the capacitor body so you can lay them down flat. Do not trust the built in footprints, each cap value with have different dimensions.

Comment: Ah, thanks, will review the capacitors then too. Good tip on laying them down flat, I would not figure that out, I would probably just soldier them in the PCB "standing".

Comment: It looks like you can scale down your MCU. There are many unused pins.

Comment: Thanks! You mean using a smaller CPU? That could be done, true. The thing is that I already bought plenty of them and exactly this type. There was almost no price difference. I need that many pins for the Relay. But you are right that I could have saved many in the switch board.

Comment: Are you having these boards made professionally? If so, why not use SMD devices for the myriad benefits they provide?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will only have pros build the PCBs with holes drilled for me, but I plan to soldier all into place myself, thus prefer the bigger pads as opposed to SMDs.

Comment: @LubošHousa This would actually be a great board to get up to speed with SMD soldering, lots of big parts. You'll miss out on a huge number parts by sticking to through hole only, and SMDs are so much easier to work with anyway. Well worth doing, especially if you're building 40 of them :)

Comment: Hello.  It's the 1980s here.  We want our thru-hole parts back.

Comment: @OlinLathrop :)

Comment: I hear you all:) As said above though I already bought all the chips, so perhaps I will try SMDs for my next project :)

Comment: It's a bit of a schizophrenic design: 1980's thru-hole parts with 2010's curved traces.

Comment: :) I don’t mind the aesthetics really. I do mind the electrical and other issues though and got plenty of feedback so far I would incorporate in upcoming days once back at my PC.

Comment: What they are hinting at here, is that through-hole PCBs are much more expensive to manufacture nowadays. We're talking of multiple times the assembly price, for nothing gained. If this is a commercial product and not just some hobby project, it sounds like a cost-sensitive application - yet you are designing for maximum expenses. In addition, SMD would reduce the board size significantly. And with multiple layers you can get better ground planes, that gives better EMC.

Comment: I get all of that. It is not meant to be commercial, only for my house instead. Main reason why I stil stick to through hole is the fact I already bought the chips. If I ever decide to go commercial (unlikely) I would change the design to SMDs indeed. I all make perfect sense. Redesigning to SMDs now would entail buying the extra SMD chips and throwing the through holes I already have to trash which would be a waste. My first project ever so I learned many valuable lessons in this thread indeed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- As mentioned in comments, some stitching vias between the two ground planes would help eliminate ground islands.
- I'd also eliminate these ground fingers that could act as little antennas:
  [image]
- Watch out for acute angles between tracks, which can cause over-etching:
  [image]

Comment: I think this answer fits well.  I do want to add that you should make sure you have appropriate footprints for the caps, as is stated in other comments.  Also, this is merely a matter of preference, but I like to keep traces to 45 degree angles, no 90s and no curves.  The reason for avoiding right angles is to minimize reflections, which probably doesn't matter in most cases, and the reason I avoid curves and other random angles is for simplicity and aesthetics, no real electrical reason.

Comment: @Redja, I actually find curves "prettier" than 45s, but I'd design with 45s for simplicity when pushing and shoving if curves aren't needed for RF reasons. But now the design is done with curves, I wouldn't spend effort on changing it to 45s.

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn’t 45degree angle be the  acute angle you previously recommended to avoid? I hope the terminology and metrics do match between our countries. 360 is full angle, 180 half, etc. anyway I would keep the curves in for now. I thought between this and 90degrees but I think 90degrees was recommended to be avoided too?

Comment: @LubošHousa, If the trace makes a 45 degree bend (say it's going north and bends to go north-east), the angle on the inner edge of the trace is 135 degrees.

Comment: If you make a tight bend (going north and bend to south-west like in the example I clipped from your board) then you end up with an acute angle between the two traces.

Comment: Here's an example of 45-degree bends: http://www.remantech.com/images/pcb2.jpg

Comment: Here's an example of an acute angle bend: http://documentation.solidworkspcb.com/sites/default/files/wiki_attachments/267121/PCB_Rul-AcuteAngle_DefaultConstraints.png

Comment: Ok got it. Missed difference between 45s bend and 45s angle between traces. All clear now.

Comment: Just one more thought. Why is the cap footprint so important? Would it matter if I lay them down and they happen to sit on a copper? Just their pins and legs can carry any signal, can’t they? I would indeed try it anyway, just curious. Also does anyone have any thoughts about the terminating resistors? I did buy in the end 51 and 56 Ohms today and do likely lean towards using 51 as being the closest to the impedance of the cables.

Comment: It will be easier to assemble your board if the cap footprint matches the actual lead spacing of your caps. Beyond that I don't think it's a critical issue given you've already decided to use thru-hole instead of SMT. The termination resistor question is probably CAN-specific and I have no experience with CAN. At 1 Mb/s matching the trace impedance is probably not important.